# How to upload files using Array index in MYSQL Database using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

Sorry if this is a noob question, i am still a newbie in codeigniter,

here is my problem,

i have a response, which is look like this

`Array([0] => Array([original_name] => avatar_img12.png [filename] => avatar_img12.png) [1] => Array([original_name]=> add_icon27.png [filename] => add_icon27.png))`

i have 2 input type textbox file thats why its only have an index of 0 and 1, i was able to upload it on my database, with the help of requiring the two input type file, but my problem is when the user will update their data,

there will be a chance that they will update the same files, or just one of them. how can i update the specific index only.

i already tried to create a if statement for each index but i am having an error of `offset 1` or `offset 0`

Here is my model

```
          if($files[0] != '' && $files[1]==''){
            $this->db->select('id,picture_id');
            $this->db->from($this->project_tbl);
            $this->db->where('id',$id);
             $query = $this->db->get();
                if($query->num_rows() > 0){
                    $this->db->where('id', $query->row()->picture_id);
                    $this->db->update($this->project_core_documents, $files[0]);
                }
            }else if($files[1] != '' && $files[0]==''){
                $this->db->select('id,detailed_report_id');
                $this->db->from($this->project_tbl);
                $this->db->where('id',$id);
                $query = $this->db->get();
                    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
                        $this->db->where('id', $query->row()->detailed_report_id);
                        $this->db->update($this->project_core_documents, $files[1]);
                    }
            }else{
                //both files
            }
```

Here is my Form

```
<form class="kt-form" id = "save_project" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" class="form-control project_userfiles" name = "userfile[]" multiple="">

<input type="file" class="form-control project_userfiles" name = "userfile[]" multiple="">
</form>
```

And this is how i am getting the array $files for uploading i am using a helper. so that i will just call it on my controller.

```
function uploadMultiple() {
    $uploadData = [];
    $ci = &get_instance(); // need this to resolve the app
    if(!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
        $filesCount = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
        for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++) {
            $_FILES['userFile']['name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['userFile']['type'] = $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['userFile']['error'] = $_FILES['userfile']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['userFile']['size'] = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i];
            $config['upload_path'] = './upload';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|doc|txt|jpg|png';
            $ci->load->library('upload', $config);
            $ci->upload->initialize($config);
            if($ci->upload->do_upload('userFile')){
                     $fileData = $ci->upload->data();
                     $uploadData[$i]['original_name'] = $fileData['file_name'];
                     $uploadData[$i]['filename'] = $fileData['file_name'];
            } else {
                // do something with the errors...
                         $error = $ci->upload->display_errors();
            }
        }
    }
    return  $uploadData;
}
```

im having an error of `undefined offset:1` if i just upload for the index[0] and `undefined offset:0` if i just upload for the index[1]
and if both index have a value there is no error and i still dont know how to execute it on my query if both index has a value. thanks in advance. sorry if my explanation is not that accurate.

Comment: Could you show the html form input that sending this files? and also what does `$files` contains ?

Comment: Hi Dhana, i editted my question. thanks for your time! and the `$files` contains this array `Array([0] => Array([original_name] => avatar_img12.png [filename] => avatar_img12.png) [1] => Array([original_name]=> add_icon27.png [filename] => add_icon27.png))`

Comment: That's a lot of code. What have you tried to debug your problems?

Comment: Hi Nico, i tried to use array_index_exist, but im still getting the error of offset 1 or offset 0

Comment: you already have mentioned `multiple` in `input` tag, so no need to write `<input type="file"` two times with same `name` attribute

Comment: @bharatparmar each field is unique, the first field is for image and the second field is for documents thats why i have 2 input field.

Comment: but `name` attributes must be unique, that's why you facing error of `undefined offset` , i think so..

Comment: @JanessaBautista So both image and document input can be multiple files?

Comment: @hasta dhana . Ahm no. I just made them as one. Thats why they have a name=userfile[] so that i will just use one function only . So there will be less code to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's get undefined index because on your upload function, if you just upload a single file, then it's only produce single upload data, so the either the `$files[0]` or `$files[1]` array would be undefined, and the *loose equality* or *loose non-equality* conditional would fail.
To get your logic working, you could use `empty` checking :

```php
if (!empty($files[0]) && empty($files[1])) {
    $this->db->select('id,picture_id');
    $this->db->from($this->project_tbl);
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $this->db->where('id', $query->row()->picture_id);
        $this->db->update($this->project_core_documents, $files[0]);
    }
} else if (!empty($files[1]) && empty($files[0])) {
    $this->db->select('id,detailed_report_id');
    $this->db->from($this->project_tbl);
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $this->db->where('id', $query->row()->detailed_report_id);
        $this->db->update($this->project_core_documents, $files[1]);
    }
} else {
    //both files
}
```

This will execute the `if` block even if one of the `$files` has an undefined index. But you should pay attention that the `else` statement will get executed if both `$files` are not empty and also if both `$files` are empty